# unable to access or expand all publications

Tags: publishing, cme, user-management

After publishing on of the child publication none of the users are able to access any of the publications. We are unable to view the contents of the publications.
The error I get is - "you do not have permission to perform this action".

I have unpublished the child publication but still no use

Please advise

thanks

event viewer recorded this error:
You do not have permission to perform this action.

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.AssertAccess(IdentifiableObjectData securedDataObject, Permissions demandedPermissions, Rights demandedRights)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Repository.OnLoaded(LoadEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Load(LoadFlags flags, Boolean forceReload)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Reload()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.get_Title()
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.UserContext.ExecutePrivileged[T](String userName, Func`1 privilegedCode)
   at Tridion.Infrastructure.Caching.Cache`3.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
   at Tridion.Infrastructure.Caching.Cache`3.GetOrCreateWithBatchRead(TKey key, TValidatorState validateState, Func`1 createNewValues)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.UserContext.b__88(<>f__AnonymousType1d`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier82)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass12`3.b__11(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.GetList(String parentItemId, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable`1 basedOnSchema)
   at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Comment: When you say the user does not have permission  to perform  the action. Can you please  check if the user have proper permission and rights  set at the publication level. If so on what level the user is getting this error at publication level or under structure group level. Provide more details.

Comment: We are getting this error at publication level. We are not even able to see the contents of the publication.

Comment: I'm not sure how publishing would affect the Publications visible to users (it shouldn't be related). If users can't see Publications, check the `Members Of` tab in the groups the users belong to. If users can select a Publication, but can't see the items within it, then check permissions. If users can't see _anything_ in a Publication including Categories & Keywords, then it's something else, not related to authorization settings.

Comment: Regarding the possible "something else," do you have an External Content Library (ECL) integration or Media Manager?

Comment: As Alvin suggested visibility of Publication should not be related to the publishing. There might be some other issue happened. Can you please check in you CM database?. May be it can help you to understand. the exact issue

Comment: Yes the error looks like ECL issue. Can you please comment the ECL part and see if the user is able to access  the publication. So you have this access issue for normal user or even system administrator. If its a ECL issue the user should have issue in accessing only the mapped folder where ECL is configured.

Comment: The issue was with media manager user account and it has been fixed. Thank you for all the comments

Comment: @user1901, can you add an answer to this question with some details on how you resolved the issue for anyone with the same problem in the future.